# C#: Generic Interfaces convert error

Tags: c#, generics

I'm actually trying to make a Base MVP framework for my system. I have `IPresenter`, `IView`, `PresenterBase<IView>` and `ViewBase<IPresenter>`.

Here is the code:

```
public interface IPresenter
{
    IAppController GetAppController();
}

public interface IView
{
    void AttachPresenter<T>(T presenter) where T : IPresenter;
}

public abstract class BasePresenter<TView> : IPresenter where TView : class, IView
{
    protected readonly TView View;
    protected readonly IAppController AppController;

    protected BasePresenter(TView view, IAppController appController)
    {
        View = view;
        AppController = appController;
        View.AttachPresenter(this);
    }

    public IAppController GetAppController()
    {
        return AppController;
    }
}

public class BaseView<TPresenter> : Form, IView where TPresenter : class, IPresenter
{
    protected TPresenter Presenter;

    public void AttachPresenter<T>(T presenter) where T : IPresenter
    {
        Presenter = presenter;  // <-- ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

When I try to set the Presenter with `AttachPresenter` method, I get this error:

" Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'TPresenter' "

Why? Both are implementing `IPresenter`. How can I solve it? I want this generic classes to implement every view and presenter in the system.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: try  `where T : class,IPresenter`

Answer (score 1):

Since you need same type of presenter you can just use:

```
public void AttachPresenter(TPresenter presenter) 
{
    Presenter = presenter;  
}
```

Comment: How I implement `void AttachPresenter(TPresenter presenter)` in the interface?

Comment: void AttachPresenter(IPresenter presenter) but yeah, you will need to change your private field to IPresenter as well.

Answer (score 1):

although `T` and `TPresenter` are implementing `IPresenter`, but the complier don't think there are same object, for example: you have an `IAnimal`, and both `Cat` and `Dog` implement `IAnimal`, but you can NOT assign a `Cat` to `Dog` like this `dog = cat`, i think that's the reason.

so, why not just change your function to

```
public void AttachPresenter(TPresenter presenter)
{
    Presenter = presenter;  
}
```

Comment: How can I add `void AttachPresenter(TPresenter presenter)` in the interface? Because I want to implement IView in the BaseView.

Comment: change your IView to `public interface IView<TPresenter> where T: IPresenter` and your function in this interface to 'void AttachPresenter(TPresenter presenter);'